# How to setup an API which allows uploading JSON data and an image?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I use [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org) to build an API. The following view set creates a database entry for a JSON object transmitted by a client.

```
class ArticleViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                    mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows articles to be created or viewed.
    """
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
```

Now, I want to send an **image together with the JSON data**. I guess that the client has to send its request as `"multipart/form-data"` mime type. Please correct me if this is wrong.
Therefore, I added a [MultiPartParser](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser):

```
parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
```

In order to debug with [*ipdb*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) the request on the server side I added the `create` method:

```
class ArticleViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                    mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows articles to be created or viewed.
    """
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

    def create(request, *args, **kwargs):
        ipdb.set_trace()
        return Response(request)
```

How can I actually inspect the `request` whether the data are received?

## Lessons learned

1. It is not necessary to configure the `MultiPartParser` since it is [loaded by default](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/3.1.1/rest_framework/settings.py#L38).
2. The signature of the `create` method I added is wrong. It has to be `create(self, request, *args, **kwargs)`. With that you will be able to inspect the `request` object and `request.data`. Thanks to *JockeTF* from IRC *#restframework* !!
3. A test request can be sent from the command line using *cURL* as follows:

   ```
   $ curl -vX POST http://localhost:8000/articles/ \
   -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
   -H "Accept:application/json" \
   -F "title=Test" \
   -F "author_name=cURL" \
   -F "article_photo=@/home/user/Desktop/article-photo.png"
   ```

Comment: I don't have any experience with the Django REST framework, but if you're using json, you can base-64 encode the file contents and deliver this as a field in your json object without needing `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did ...

1. Install the [Pillow package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/) for image processing
2. Extend your model with a new attribute

   ```
   article_photo = models.ImageField(blank=True)
   ```
3. In *settings.py* configure the following settings:

   - for the **development** environment:

     ```
     ENV_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

     """
     Absolute filesystem path to the directory that 
     will hold user-uploaded files.
     """
     MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(ENV_PATH, 'media/')

     """
     Relative browser URL you should access your media files from
     """
     MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
     ```
   - for the **production** environment:

     ```
     """
     Absolute filesystem path to the directory that 
     will hold user-uploaded files.
     """
     MEDIA_ROOT = '/myapp/api/media'

     """
     Relative browser URL you should access your media files from
     Path must be served from webserver (Nginx, Apache, ..) configuration
     """
     MEDIA_URL = '/myapp/media/'
     ```
4. Create a new migration and run it.

   ```
   $ python manage.py makemigrations  
   $ python manage.py migrate
   ```
5. Send a test request from the command line using *cURL* as follows:

   ```
   $ curl -vX POST http://localhost:8000/articles/ \
   -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
   -H "Accept:application/json" \
   -F "title=Test" \
   -F "author_name=cURL" \
   -F "article_photo=@/home/user/Desktop/article-photo.png"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes your client should do something like this (js example)

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("image", file);
```

in Django the uploaded file is accessible in request.FILES['image']

Check Django doc for this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/file-uploads/